# A C/C++ Program that will output as a Speed Test Quiz

Tags: c++, c, timer

I am a 1st year IT student. Well, our professor gave a project. The project should be a simple C/C++ program that will help others.

I choose to make a project about,test speed for children. The test speed will consist of Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication and Division Problems. I am worried because I don't know how to write a code for a timer. Because it's a test speed a timer is a MUST. And also, how can I check the answers if they got it right or wrong and will print the number of items they get right.

I hope, somebody can help me with my problem. 
Thank you! :)

Comment: Keep in mind there's a `<chrono>` header so you don't have to rely on non-standard functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
clock_t start = clock();

clock_t total = clock() - start;
```

### Note

If you use `clock()`, the time you get is not (milli-)seconds but CPU Clock ticks

### Header

include < time.h >

### Reference

[time_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/) & [clock()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/)

### Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    double Start = clock();
    //...
    // Ask question to the user
    //...
    printf("Elapsed Time: %f milliseconds", clock()-Start);
}
```

Comment: Clock is a little harsh. time(0) from time.h will probably be enough, and its already in seconds.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett but `clock()` is in milliseconds

Comment: I still don't get it. Sorry, I try to understand it but I cannot. Can you give me an example code for this? thanks! :)

Comment: @user3027129 I added the example. It can be compiled perfectly with GCC. If this is helpful, you can click to set this as an accepted answers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/

```
/* clock example: frequency of primes */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <time.h>       /* clock_t, clock, CLOCKS_PER_SEC */
#include <math.h>       /* sqrt */

int frequency_of_primes (int n) {
  int i,j;
  int freq=n-1;
  for (i=2; i<=n; ++i) for (j=sqrt(i);j>1;--j) if (i%j==0) {--freq; break;}
  return freq;
}

int main ()
{
  clock_t t;
  int f;
  t = clock();
  printf ("Calculating...\n");
  f = frequency_of_primes (99999);
  printf ("The number of primes lower than 100,000 is: %d\n",f);
  t = clock() - t;
  printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",t,((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}
```

Be aware that `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` gives you the current clock speed and usually in modern computers it varies due to power settings. so you might have to do something more intelligent to get a more accurate result.